# How to shape the physics Phaser 3 bodies of a JSON animation

Tags: javascript, game-physics, physics, phaser-framework

I am making a platformer to learn Phaser. I got some sprites from itch.io for making my hero. The Hero contained attack movements, so I am making a combat system based on those attacks.  After searching on the internet I came across a similar TexturePacker for physics: [How to create physics shapes for Phaser 3 and Matter JS](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/tutorials/how-to-create-physics-shapes-for-phaser-3-and-matterjs).

I have already animated those attacks with TexturePacker.

Is there a way to shape the body (with PhysicsEditor) of each frame of my animation so that I can hit my game enemies?